# Sort multidimensional array by another array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am beginner with C.I have two files
second.txt

```
0 0 1.200
1 0 1.200
2 0 1.200
3 0 1.200
1 1 1.400 
2 1 1.420
3 1 1.480
0 1 1.400
0 2 1.500
2 2 1.520
3 2 1.540
1 2 1.500
```

newindex.txt

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
```

I want to write file like this(third column value should be written in proper indexing)

```
0.0 0.0 1.2
1.0 0.0 1.2
2.0 0.0 1.2
3.0 0.0 1.2
0.0 1.0 1.4
1.0 1.0 1.4
2.0 1.0 1.42
3.0 1.0 1.48
0.0 2.0 1.5
1.0 2.0 1.5
2.0 2.0 1.52
3.0 2.0 1.54
```

I have written this comparison function

```
 int my_cmp(const void *a_, const void *b_,void *arg_)
 {
   const int *a = a_, *b = b_;

   if(B[*a][1] == B[*b][1])
       return 0;
    else if (B[*a][1] < B[*b][1])
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;

}
```

But what to do next?Should I use qsort,if yes,how?

Comment: Whats the use of `void *arg_` here =>> `int my_cmp(const void *a_, const void *b_,void *arg_)`?

Comment: @Michi Yes,that is mistake,now deleted.

Comment: Sort by another, you mean to create another sorted Array?

Comment: @Michi Yes,take a look the index arrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the `float` value at the end of each line in `second.txt`, you need only read those values into an array to be sorted. The `newindex.txt` file provides everything else you will need to complete each line in your new output file. In essence all you are doing is reading the floats from `second.txt` sorting them, and adding them to the end of each line in `newindex.txt`

The code below will read from `second.txt` and `newindex.txt` (by default) or take the file names provided by the first and second arguments to the program. (you must provide *both* arguments to provide an alternative file for `newindex.txt`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAXC = 16, MAXF = 32 };  /* constants for buffer and array size */

int cmpfloat (const void *a, const void *b);  /* qsort comparison */
void rmlf (char *s);                          /* trim newline    */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t i = 0, idx = 0;
    float ftmp, second[MAXF] = {0.0};
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "second.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate "second.txt" open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed (second).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (idx < MAXF && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) /* read each line    */
        if (sscanf (buf, " %*d %*d %f", &ftmp)) /* parse float value */
            second[idx++] = ftmp;      /* add to array, update index */
    fclose (fp);

    qsort (second, idx, sizeof *second, cmpfloat); /* sort floats */

    /* open/validate "newindex" for reading */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "newindex.txt", "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed (newindex).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (i < idx && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {  /* read each line */
        rmlf (buf);                             /* trim newline   */
        printf ("%s %.2f\n", buf, second[i++]); /* write sorted output */
    }

    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}

/* qsort comparison for floats */
int cmpfloat (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    /* (a > b) - (a < b) */
    return (*(float *)a > *(float *)b) - (*(float *)a < *(float *)b);
}

/* trim newline from end of string */
void rmlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;
    for (; *s && *s != '\n'; s++) {}
    *s = 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

Using your data files as input, you can produce your desired output.

```
$ ./bin/qsortnewindex
0 0 1.20
1 0 1.20
2 0 1.20
3 0 1.20
0 1 1.40
1 1 1.40
2 1 1.42
3 1 1.48
0 2 1.50
1 2 1.50
2 2 1.52
3 2 1.54
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Writing Output with** `fwrite`

As indicated in the comment, if you are intending to write output with `fwrite` to a file, you will be writing the output in *binary* format. That is fine, but understand if you want to look at the file, you will see nothing but gibberish (data, not *characters*). If you want to write what you see printed to the screen to a file as *formatted text*, then you want the `fprintf` function which works the same as `printf` except you provide a `FILE *` stream pointer to which the output is written.

(If you want the formatted output in a file, the simple way is to redirect the original program output to a file from the command line, e.g. `./qsortnewindex > filename.txt`, however that doesn't provide the decimal points you show as your desired output.)

Since you need to understand both reading and writing with `fwrite` as well as with `fprintf`, the example below shows both. While there was no requirement to use a 2D array to hold all values at once, it does simplify the `fwrite` call, so I have rearranged the storage so that all values (`newindex.txt` and sorted `second.txt`) are held in the 2D array named creatively enough `array`.

Go over each part of the example to insure you understand what it taking place. Since you cannot simply look at the binary data and confirm it was properly written, the end of the code reads the data back in from the binary output file `newindex.dat` and displays that information on screen. (you can look at it with programs like `hexdump`, `od`, or `bvi`)

The formatted text file created is `newindex.dat.txt`. You can simply look at that file to confirm the output. Also note, the `qsort` compare function has changed to sort on the 3rd column of the array.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* constants for new index cols, buffer and second array size */
enum { NCOL = 3, MAXC = 11, MAXF = 12 };

int cmpfloat (const void *a, const void *b);  /* qsort comparison */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t i = 0, idx = 0;
    float ftmp, ftmp2, array[MAXF][NCOL] = {{0.0}};
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "second.txt", "r");

    if (!fp) {  /* validate "second.txt" open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed (second).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (idx < MAXF && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))   /* read each line    */
        if (sscanf (buf, " %*d %*d %f", &ftmp))   /* parse float value */
            array[idx++][NCOL-1] = ftmp; /* add to array, update index */
    fclose (fp);

    /* sort floats in last col */
    qsort (array, idx, sizeof *array, cmpfloat);

    /* open/validate "newindex" for reading */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "newindex.txt", "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed (newindex).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line, parse values into float array */
    for (i = 0; i < idx && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp);) {
        if (sscanf (buf, " %f %f", &ftmp, &ftmp2) == 2) {
            array[i][0] = ftmp;
            array[i][1] = ftmp2;
            i++;
        }
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to parse values from '%s'.\n",
                     "newindex.txt");
    }
    fclose (fp);

    if (i != idx) { /* validate rows match second.txt */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: mismatch in data between newindex and second.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* open/validate "newindex.dat" for output (binary) */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "newindex.dat", "w"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat");
        return 1;
    }

    /* write array to output file in binary using fwrite */
    if (fwrite (array, sizeof *array, idx, fp) != idx)
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file write failed '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat");

    if (fclose (fp))    /* check for error on close (errno set) */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failure on file close '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat");

    /* open/validate "newindex.dat.txt" for output (formatted text) */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "newindex.dat.txt", "w"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    /* write array to output file in formatted text using fprintf */
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        fprintf (fp, "%.1f %.1f %.2f\n", 
                array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);

    if (fclose (fp))    /* check for error on close (errno set) */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failure on file close '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat.txt");

    /* confirm output values -- open/validate "newindex.dat" */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "newindex.dat", "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat");
        return 1;
    }

    float b[MAXF][NCOL] = {{0.0}};  /* read binary data into array */
    if (fread (b, sizeof *b, idx, fp) != idx)
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file write failed '%s'.\n",
                 "newindex.dat");

    fclose (fp);

    printf ("\narray values read from binary file '%s'.\n\n",
            "newindex.dat");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)   /* output data from file */
        printf ("%.1f %.1f %.2f\n", b[i][0], b[i][1], b[i][2]);

    return 0;
}

/* qsort comparison for floats */
int cmpfloat (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const float *ia = (const float *)a;
    const float *ib = (const float *)b;
    return (ia[NCOL-1] > ib[NCOL-1]) - (ia[NCOL-1] < ib[NCOL-1]);
}
```

**Example Output**

The program reads the values written to the binary file `newindex.dat` using `fwrite`:

```
$ ./bin/qsortnewindex2

array values read from binary file 'newindex.dat'.

0.0 0.0 1.20
1.0 0.0 1.20
2.0 0.0 1.20
3.0 0.0 1.20
0.0 1.0 1.40
1.0 1.0 1.40
2.0 1.0 1.42
3.0 1.0 1.48
0.0 2.0 1.50
1.0 2.0 1.50
2.0 2.0 1.52
3.0 2.0 1.54
```

You can also confirm that the formatted text ouput file was created properly:

```
$ cat newindex.dat.txt
0.0 0.0 1.20
1.0 0.0 1.20
2.0 0.0 1.20
3.0 0.0 1.20
0.0 1.0 1.40
1.0 1.0 1.40
2.0 1.0 1.42
3.0 1.0 1.48
0.0 2.0 1.50
1.0 2.0 1.50
2.0 2.0 1.52
3.0 2.0 1.54
```

Comment: Works perfect,just I have a question about the buffer constant.I will have also huge files,how to set the constants in that case?

Comment: You simply size the constants for your reasonably anticipated array size. If you do not know the size, you can dynamically allocate memory for your array (with `calloc` - or `malloc`) and then if you reach your limit, you can `realloc` the array to create a larger block of memory  and keep going. (there are many, many examples of dynamic allocation of arrays on S.O. - I know...) You will have to dynamically allocate memory if you have more than ~ 250,000 lines due to stack limitations. For your buffer, it just must be sufficient for the line size `256` - `4096` are the normal range.

Comment: @RichardRublev In other words, with your example, based on the longest line in `second` being `9` characters (and then adding `+1` for the `'\n'` and `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character) you have a minimum `MAXC` of `11`, and based on the fact you have `12` float values, you have a minimum `MAXF` of `12`. (e.g. `enum { MAXC = 11, MAXF = 12 };`). But unless you are memory-critical, it's always a safe-bet to provide a few extra characters or floats (even though if you appropriately limit your input -- you will never need them...)

Comment: I have solved this problem with malloc.Just one issue more,how to change printf line to fwrite,in order to write output to new file?

Comment: Piece of cake. Now you understand `fwrite` will output in binary. That's fine, but you will need to read in binary.That is fine, but it will not be human readable. If you want the new file human readable, use `fprintf`. I'll drop an example in my answer.

Comment: This is really excellent,I would like to change binary output,just to write the third array column,everything else should stay the same.How to do this?

Comment: With all three columns combined in the 2D array, you can loop over each row (e.g. `for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)`) and `fwrite` each value to the output file (e.g. `fwrite (&array[i][NCOL-1], sizeof array[i][NCOL-1], 1, fp)`) or just use the first version with the 1D array and write that entire array to the file. Give it a shot and I'll help if you get stuck. You have good examples to go by.

Comment: Works now perfect!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. There is quite a bit of the basics of C tied up in this example. It is well worth the while to take time and make sure it all sinks in. You will use these basics over and over again. Good luck with your coding.